# CAShapeLayer fill color swift 4 xcode 9 iOS 11 not working any idea?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4, cashapelayer

I have been trying to fill color in `CAShapeLayer` in XCode 9 iOS 11 using Swift 4 but no success.

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 12, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise: true)
let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
circleLayer.lineWidth = 1.5
```

Comment: First, check that you added this to the view's layer properly. Second, check the `frame` of the view to which you added this (e.g. with view debugger or the like). As an aside, it's a little weird to use center of `.zero` and then go from 0 to 2π (because presumably three quarters of that circle will not be within the frame of the view to which you added it). Also unrelated, I'd suggest simplifying `endAngle` to just `CGFloat.pi * 2` or `.pi * 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you forgot to set a frame. For instance:

```
circleLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 6, y: 6, width: 12, height: 12)
```

Comment: I suspect you meant `x` and `y` values of `12` (the radius) or `12.75` (the radius plus half the line width) or `13` or something like that. And you should change the `width` and `height` correspondingly. (Personally, I hate having layers with the origins moved around, so I'd personally move the `center` of the `UIBezierPath` rather than the `origin` of the `CALayer`, but this works, too.) All of this said, this wouldn't affect the circle not showing up. The way he has it, you should at least see a quadrant of the circle. I suspect something else is wrong.